# spark streaming & kafka : direct approach --some confusions

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Recently， I am trying to integrate spark streaming and kafka with its direct approach. In my app ,I need to periodically update a *List* dataset loading from elasticsearch. I wrote a Thread to do this, but the *List* were not updated when I run the app in my spark cluster.

However, when I integrated spark streaming and kafka with its receiver-based approach and used the same Thread, the *List* were updated.

Can someone explain it to me ? BTW, is there an effective way to do this(periodicaly updating dataset)? Thanks!

Below is some of my code:
The direct approach main method:

```
if (args.length < 2) {
    System.err.println("Usage: DirectKafkaWordCount <brokers> <topics>\n"
    + "  <brokers> is a list of one or more Kafka brokers\n"
    + "  <topics> is a list of one or more kafka topics to consume from\n\n");
    System.exit(1);
}
String brokers = args[0];
String topics = args[1];

// Create context with 2 second batch interval
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DirectReceiverLogAnalysis");
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true");

// Create the streaming context with a 2 second batch size
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(getContext(conf),new Duration(2000));

// 初始化rule
loadRules(jssc.sparkContext());

// 定期更新rule
RuleThread ruleThread = new RuleThread(jssc.sparkContext());
ruleThread.start();

HashSet<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(topics.split(",")));

HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);

// Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils
    .createDirectStream(jssc, String.class, String.class,
    StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams,topicsSet);

// Get the lines
JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>,     String>() {
        public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                        return tuple2._2();
                    }
                });

        // get the windowDstream
        JavaDStream<String> windowed_messageDStream = lines.window(
                new Duration(6000), new Duration(4000));

        // dispose of the streams with rules
        windowed_messageDStream
                .foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {

                    public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (rdd.count() > 0) {

                            SQLContext sqlContext = JavaSQLContextSingleton
                                    .getInstance(rdd.context());

                            DataFrame json_rdd = sqlContext.jsonRDD(rdd);

                            json_rdd.registerTempTable("logs");

                            json_rdd.printSchema();

                            System.out
                                    .println("---------------size-------------"
                                            + sqlList.size());
                            // 数据匹配
                            for (int i = 0; i < sqlList.size(); i++) {

                                try {
                                    DataFrame result = sqlContext.sql(sqlList
                                            .get(i));


                                    if (result.count() > 0) {
                                        JavaEsSparkSQL.saveToEs(result,
                                                "matching/logs");
                                        }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }

                            }

                        }

                        return null;
                    }
                });

        // Start the computation
        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();

        // 终止线程
        ruleThread.setStop(true);

    }

    // 加载rules
    public static void loadRules(JavaSparkContext context) {
        // 初始化rule
        JavaRDD<Map<String, Object>> esRDD = JavaEsSpark.esRDD(context,
                "sql_rules/logs").values();

        // collect the rules to list
        sqlList = esRDD.map(new Function<Map<String, Object>, String>() {

            public String call(Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {

                return (String) map.get("sql");
            }
        }).collect();
    }


The thread class:
public class RuleThread extends Thread {

    public boolean threadStop = false;

    public JavaSparkContext context;

    public RuleThread(JavaSparkContext context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setStop(boolean stop) {

        this.threadStop = stop;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (!threadStop) {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 1);
                LogAnalysis.loadRules(context);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

}

Comment: With the reciever based approach, the zookeeper address is used  (host:2181). Whereas in the direct approach we use the Kafka broker address (host:9092)  .Are you sure you are not mixing them up ?

Comment: can you update your question with some code?

Comment: @Clyde D'Cruz：thanks for the reply! I don't think you understood my question. What i want to ask is updating data in spark streaming app using thread which works in reciever-based approach but don't work in direct approach.

Comment: Can you also include the command you are using to start the application ?for direct , and receiver based approach ?

Comment: @ClydeD'Cruz: 
for receiver-based approach: spark-submit --class driver-class --master spark:192.168.122.61:7077 the-app-jar zookeeper-url group-name topic-name threads-num checkPoint-dir

Comment: @ClydeD'Cruz: 
for direct approach:
spark-submit --class driver-class --master spark:192.168.122.61:7077 the-app-jar broker-list topics

Comment: What are the values for zookeeper-url and broker-list ?

Comment: @ClydeD'Cruz: zookeeper-url----192.168.122.61:2181
broker-list----192.168.122.61:9092. Does this matter?